# Cannot remove root and Kingroot

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I installed Kingroot  and rooted my phone. I don't know how it happened but Kingroot became my system application and now it cannt be removed. If I open Kingroot and go to its settings and try to remove root, it says we have a problem removing root. Kingroot has became my system application and now what I can do is only disable it like other system apps

Answer (score 0):

Download [Uninstall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp) from Google Play. It's a system apps remover. You'll be able to remove Kingroot app from your phone.